# Airflow can't find file path (credentials.json)

Tags: python, google-sheets, airflow

> This is the code that i use to connect google sheet with database
> I use credentials.json file download from google console
> And i did put it in the correct path like below but it generates the error
> when i run it. what is wrong? how can i fix this error?
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/airflow/data/credentials.json'

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import gspread
import os

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG 
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


default_args = {
    'owner':'rei',
    'retries':1,
    'retry_delay':timedelta(minutes=5)
}

# Connect to Google Sheet using gspread and service account credentials
def connect_data_from_gsheet():
    credentials_file = '/opt/airflow/data/credentials.json'
  # Use the correct absolute file path
    gc = gspread.service_account(filename=credentials_file)

    # Open the Google Sheet
    sheet = gc.open("MDA_team_member_copy")
```

Comment: might be permissions problem because airflow runs with airflow user and not root. run chmod 777 to see if it helps

Comment: which executor are you using?

Comment: @HusseinAwala yes, i am using CeleryExercutor. do i need to change to other executor?

Comment: Did you check if the file `/opt/airflow/data/credentials.json` is present in all the workers and in the same path?